# catch PDOException in laravel

Tags: php, pdo, laravel

I am currently trying to catch a PDOException in Laravel, and allow my app to continue after catching the error. I have tried multiple try catches in different locations but I cannot catch the error before it makes the app fail.

here is my model:

```
class Oracle extends Eloquent {

  protected $connection = 'oracle';
  protected $user = '';
  protected $table = '';
  public $timestamps = false;

  public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    DB::reconnect('oracle');
    $this->table = Config::get('database.connections.oracle.table');
    $this->user = Config::get('database.connections.oracle.username');
  }

  public function scopegetPerms($callback, $db) {
    return $callback->select('*')->where('grantee', '=', strtoupper(trim($this->user)))->orderBy('granted_role');
  }

}
```

I am updating the `oracle` connection settings on the fly and using the `DB::reconnect` function to pick up the changes. everything is working as expected. I would like to be able to catch an invalid user/password exception and continue notifying the user later. but my attempts to catch the exception have not worked.

I have attempted to put a try/catch around both `DB::reconnect()` and around the query itself.

here is the error I am getting:

```
{"error":{"type":"PDOException","message":"ORA-01017: invalid username\/password; logon denied"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run

`new Oracle`

surround that in try{}catch{} like this:

```
try {
new Oracle; 
}catch(PDOException $e){ 
//Do whatever. 
}
```